# TypeLoadException, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

Consider my project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="3.0.0-preview4-19123-01" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0-preview5-19227-01" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    [..]

    services.
        AddMvc().
        AddNewtonsoftJson(); // Here is the problem
}
```

Whenever I try to load NewonsoftJson formatters I get this view when running my API:

[image: Crash and burn]

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

How should I interpret this, why are the formatters not where they are expected to be found? Is it even looking for the correct formatter?

Comment: did you try to delete obj and bin folders and rebuild ?

Comment: Yes, many times.

Comment: Remove `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` and upgrade others packages to 3.0.0-preview5-*

Comment: If I remove this package I have no way of adding JsonFormatters at all, the extension method AddNewtonsoftJson is located in this package. There are no exact preview matches of the packages in my solution. I have tried the latest of everything with the same result.

Comment: what's the sdk you use ? `dotnet --version`. I just create a new mvc project using `dotnet new mvc` with sdk 3.0.100-preview5-011568, It wrote the code : `services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson();` and  add <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0-preview5-19227-01" /> in csproj.

Comment: So you should replace `service.AddMvc` by `services.AddControllersWithViews()`

Comment: @aguafrommars - Why whould I do that? I am implementing a Web API with a complete separate SPA. I have no views, this is not an MVC project.

Comment: Use `services.AddControllers()` then. I suppose you use controllers

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this error as well but using

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

which is currently working in dotnet core 3.0 preview 5